# Question about shell commands and grep

Tags: linux, grep

Does anyone know why

```
grep "p\{2\}" textfile
```

will find "apple" if it's in the file, but

```
grep p\{2\} textfile
```

won't?

I'm new to using a command line and regular expressions, and this is puzzling me.

Comment: I think you made a more interesting find the answers posted below. grep shouldn't support what your typing without the -e switch, but it seems to if you enclose it in quotes. I'll keep looking but but would be interested to see what the answer is.

Comment: @nsfyn55: grep perfectly supports what zjmiller is typing. In the above case, where `e` option is not indicated, `G` option is used by default. It's the same as `grep -G "p\{2\}" textfile`.

Comment: @empo yeah I get it now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With quotes, your complete regex gets passed directly to grep. Without the quotes, grep sees your regex as `p{2}`.

Edit:

To clarify, without the quotes your slashes are being removed by shell before your regex is passed to grep.

Try:

```
echo grep p\{2\} test.txt
```

And you'll see your output as...

```
grep p{2} test.txt
```

The quotes prevent shell from escaping characters before they get to grep. You could also escape your slashes and it will work without quotes - `grep p\\{2\\} test.txt`

Comment: grep doesn't support regex without the -e option. I have tried this out a number of ways and have no idea why it works one way and not the other

Comment: grep s{2} pom.xml returns nothing, but grep "s\{2\}" pom.xml returns all the instances of the word assembly. grep s\{2\} also returns nothing

Comment: Wait, what? `-e` is a convenience for patterns that start with `-` (and predates the `--` convention). `grep` supports POSIX BREs (and, as a GNU extension, ERE syntax backslashed); `{}` is defined in POSIX BREs to require backslashes (but not in EREs, which is where GNU got the idea for its extension).

Comment: If you don't specify the `-e` option, grep will use the first argument as the search pattern. I can't really think of a situation right now where you might need to specify otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Although this has already been answered, but since you are new to all this stuff, here is how to debug it:

-- get the pid of current shell (using `ps`).

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD

 1611 pts/0    00:00:00 su

 1619 pts/0    00:00:00 bash

 1763 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

-- from some other shell, attach `strace` (system call tracer) to the required pid (here 1619):

`strace -f -o <output_file> -p 1619`

-- Run both the commands that you tried

-- open the output file and look for `exec` family calls for the required process, here: `grep`

The output on my machine is some thing like:

```
1723  execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "--color=auto", "p{2}", "foo"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0

1725  execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "--color=auto", "p\\{2\\}", "foo"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
```

Now you can see the difference how `grep` was executed in both the cases and can figure out the problem yourself. :)

still the -e flag mystery is yet to be solved....

Answer (score 1):

Without the quotes, the shell will try to expanding the options. In your case the curly brackets '{}' have a special meaning in the shell much like the asterisk '*' which expands to a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

From the grep man page

```
In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
```

so these two become functional equivalent

```
egrep p{2}
```

and

```
grep "p\{2\}"
```

the first uses EREs(Extended Regular Expressions) the second uses BREs(Basic Regular Expressions) in your example because your using grep(which supports BREs when you don't use the -e switch) and you're enclosed in quotes so "\{" gets expanded as a special BRE character.

You second instance doesn't work because your just looking for the literal string 2{p} which doesn't exist in your file

you can demonstrate that grep is expanding your string as a BRE by trying:

```
grep "p\{2"
```

grep will complain

```
grep: Unmatched \{
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one greps the pattern using regex, then `pp`:

```
echo "apple" | grep 'p\{2\}'
```

The second one greps the pattern literally, then `p{2}`:

```
echo "ap{2}le" | grep p\{2\}
```